# GTA IV won't start: 'SecuLauncer failed to start application' error?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-iv

When I click play on GTA 4 (steam) I get the Rockstar Social Club login (which I can log in fine), but after that this shows up:

[image: SecuLauncer failed to start application]

How do I fix this, so I can play the game?

Comment: That sounds like you're running something on your system that GTA4's DRM doesn't like.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the Visual Studio C++ redistributable and the .NET 3.5 framework?

Answer (score 2):

From [SecuROM's website](https://support.securom.com/pop_gtaiv.html):

> Please note that this is a common issue when the Visual Studio C++ redistributable and/or Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 was not installed properly.
>
> 1. To solve the issue, please open your Windows Explorer/My Computer and switch to the following directory on the 'Grand Theft Auto IV' Disc #1: e.g. E:\GTAIV\Redistributable.
>
>    If you own the Steam download version, please open your installation path of 'Grand Theft Auto IV': e.g. C:/Progra...steamapps/common/grand theft auto iv/installers.
>
>    In that folder you will find a file called 'vcredist_x86.exe'. Please execute this application and follow the installation wizard.
> 2. Please also download and install the latest version of [Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=333325FD-AE52-4E35-B531-508D977D32A6&displaylang=en).
>
> After you have successfully installed the Visual Studio C++ redistributable and Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 please perform the recommended reboot. 'Grand Theft Auto IV' should start fine now.

Technically, this is something that Steam should have handled when you first ran it.  But ensuring you have the correct dependencies installed should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem as well even after installing the Visual C++ redistributable.  Turns out the problem was that the game does not like being installed on a drive that has NTFS Compression enabled.  So if you have it installed on a drive with compression enabled you'll need to move it.

Answer (score -1):

Umm... I'm not sure id I should have this as an answer or a comment, but I managed to launch the game. I didn't do any fancy installing of any programs, I just waited about a week and tried playing it launching it again. It worked normally and now I'm playing GTA IV with no problems.

Comment: Steam may have updated the game files in that time, fixing the issue